# how to make a script that understands pagination

Tags: php, pagination

i looking to make a small script that will understand pagination of urls i input and advance the pagination forever.

my input example, 2 strings:

```
hello14.com/14/oijosij
hello14.com/15/oijosij
```

script should output:

```
hello14.com/14/oijosij
hello14.com/15/oijosij
hello14.com/16/oijosij
hello14.com/17/oijosij
hello14.com/18/oijosij
hello14.com/19/oijosij
```

and forever and forever.

it must be able to handle many variations of urls, not just this spesific case.

if you look at my code below, you see where i run into trouble.
it detects if there IS pagination in the urls, but i dont know how to detect the right position of where the pagination is located.
i cannot just explode the pagination number found, that will result in error, as my example contains the first pagination-number also elsewhere in the url.

```
$string1 = "hello14.com/14/oijosij";
$string2 = "hello14.com/15/oijosij";

// match all spans of numbers
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{1,}/", $string1, $out);
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{1,}/", $string2, $out2);

// loop through all spans of numbers found in string 1
for ($loop = 0; $loop < count($out[0]); $loop++) {
  if ($out2[0][$loop] - $out[0][$loop] == 1) {
    echo "we have pagination. ".$out[0][$loop]." and ".$out2[0][$loop];
    // but how can i go about it here?
  }
}
```

Comment: the output of the script above will in the end be: `hello1.com/14/oijosij` `hello1.com/15/oijosij` `hello1.com/16/oijosij` `hello1.com/17/oijosij` and so on. was that not clear, im sorry

Comment: Kristian, it's really more the tone of your question that's earning you downvotes, I think. It sounds like you're asking us to write this for you, which is inappropriate and rude. If you can describe what you're having trouble with, and where you need help, I think you'll get a better reception.

Comment: ah, sorry that was not intentional, im just very tired :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there must be a very different&easier approach to this, but I did what I could with what I knew

```
 <?php
    //into an ugly function...
    function get_structure($str1, $str2){
        preg_match_all("/\d+/",$str1, $out1);
        preg_match_all("/\d+/",$str2, $out2);
        $parts = preg_split("/\d+/",$str1);
        $total = count($out1[0]);
        for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
            if($out2[0][$i] - $out1[0][$i] == 1){
                $left = "";
                for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){
                    $left .= $j == $i ? $parts[$j] : $parts[$j].$out1[0][$j];
                }
                $right = "";
                for($j=$i+1;$j<=$total;$j++){
                    $right .= $j == $total ? $parts[$j] : $parts[$j].$out1[0][$j];
                }
                return array($left, $right, $out2[0][$i]);
            }   
        }
        return false;
    }


    //using it
    $str1 = "13hello1415duh.com/2011/13/yay";
    $str2 = "13hello1415duh.com/2011/14/yay";
    if($parts = get_structure($str1, $str2)){
        list($left,$right,$number) = $parts;
        while($number < 30){ //it has to stop..
            $number++;
            echo $left.$number.$right."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your try. however it doesnt output anything when i test it. $parts isnt set, so you are checking null against the function?

Comment: weird, is working for me :( anyway right there where you're seeing I'm assigning, checking would be ==
Still I saw your edit about having the number more than once on the string so I'm trying to address that issue.

Comment: thanks alot. that might occur if theres a date or something in the url, which can be typical for blogs.

Comment: edited to add my last try LOL I really really hope someone who knows better comes and post their solution